# Trigger e outro campo

Tags: postgresql, trigger

No postgres tenho duas tabelas, test1(id_test1,name) e test2(id_test2, test1_id_test1, phone)

No form do PHP tenho o campo nome e fone. Quando gravo nome em test1, uma trigger replica a chave primaria em test2(test1_id_test1)

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_test2
  AFTER INSERT
  ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_test2();
```

>

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_test2()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
INSERT INTO test2
    (test1_id_test1)
VALUES
    (new.id_test1);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Com um SQL INSERT com RETURNING consigo gravar o fone em test2 e assim poderia até dispensar a trigger, mas será que existe maneira mais otimizada de efetuar a gravação, aproveitando a trigger e tirando a carga do PHP?

Comment: Mas a trigger só é disparada na insersão de test1, certo? Para o caso onde voce insira mais de 1 telefone, ai voce usa o metodo em PHP. Nesta caso eu vejo dois métodos diferentes que fazem a mesma coisa. Um método de inserçao na Test2 para quando um registro na Test1 é criado e outro quando o registro de Test1 já existe.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de uma `TRIGGER` de replicação para isso. No seu caso, uma `TRIGGER` parece não fazer sentido algum e certamente está só complicando a coisa.

Se a sua aplicação está fazendo o `INSERT` do registro em uma tabela, pode perfeitamente fazer o `INSERT` dos demais registros na outra, desde que você faça tudo dentro de uma única transação.

Você mencionou o uso de [`INSERT/RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dml-returning.html), e com base nisso, acredito que você está usando o tipo [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html) em suas chaves primárias.

Em `PostgreSQL`, toda vez que você cria uma campo dos tipo `SMALLSERIAL`, `SERIAL` ou `BIGSERIAL`, uma [`SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) é criada implicitamente para fazer o controle de auto-incremento desse campo, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_teste ( id BIGSERIAL, nome TEXT );
```

Saída:

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "tb_teste_id_seq" for serial column "tb_teste.id"
Query returned successfully with no result in 377 msec.
```

Repare que a `SEQUENCE` de nome `tb_teste_id_seq` foi criada para fazer o controle do campo `id` da tabela `tb_teste`.

Você também pode usar a função [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) para se consultar qual `SEQUENCE` está por trás do controle de um determinado campo de auto-incremento:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence( 'tb_teste', 'id' );
```

Saída:

```
| pg_get_serial_sequence |
|------------------------|
| public.tb_teste_id_seq |
```

A partir do nome da `SEQUENCE` de controle do campo de auto-incremento, é possível se obter por meio da função [`currval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html), o ultimo identificador inserido na tabela `tb_teste`, veja só:

```
INSERT INTO tb_teste ( nome ) VALUES ( 'foobar' ); 
SELECT currval('tb_teste_id_seq');
```

Presumo que sua estrutura seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pessoa
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tb_telefone
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_pessoa INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tb_pessoa( id ),
  numero TEXT
);
```

Consultando `SEQUENCES`:

```
SELECT
    pg_get_serial_sequence( 'tb_pessoa', 'id' ),
    pg_get_serial_sequence( 'tb_telefone', 'id' );
```

Saída:

```
|  pg_get_serial_sequence |    pg_get_serial_sequence |
|-------------------------|---------------------------|
| public.tb_pessoa_id_seq | public.tb_telefone_id_seq |
```

Cadastrando `Pessoas` e `Telefones`:

```
-- CADASTRANDO MARIA COM 3 TELEFONES
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( nome ) VALUES ( 'MARIA' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '9999-1234' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '8181-1020' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '9911-3344' );
COMMIT;    

-- CADASTRANDO JOAO COM 2 TELEFONES
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( nome ) VALUES ( 'JOAO' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '9799-3579' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '9191-9020' );
COMMIT;

-- CADASTRANDO JESUS COM 2 TELEFONES
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tb_pessoa ( nome ) VALUES ( 'JESUS' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '8591-0666' );
INSERT INTO tb_telefone ( id_pessoa, numero ) VALUES ( currval('tb_pessoa_id_seq'), '9581-0001' );
COMMIT;
```

Consultando:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.nome,
  tel.numero
FROM
  tb_pessoa AS p
JOIN
  tb_telefone AS tel ON ( tel.id_pessoa = p.id );
```

Saída:

```
| id |  nome |    numero |
|----|-------|-----------|
|  1 | MARIA | 9999-1234 |
|  1 | MARIA | 8181-1020 |
|  1 | MARIA | 9911-3344 |
|  2 |  JOAO | 9799-3579 |
|  2 |  JOAO | 9191-9020 |
|  3 | JESUS | 8591-0666 |
|  3 | JESUS | 9581-0001 |
```

Ou, agregando os telefones em um mesmo registro:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.nome,
  string_agg( tel.numero, ' / ' )
FROM
  tb_pessoa AS p
JOIN
  tb_telefone AS tel ON ( tel.id_pessoa = p.id )
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.nome;
```

Saída:

```
| id |  nome |                        string_agg |
|----|-------|-----------------------------------|
|  1 | MARIA | 9999-1234 / 8181-1020 / 9911-3344 |
|  2 |  JOAO |             9799-3579 / 9191-9020 |
|  3 | JESUS |             8591-0666 / 9581-0001 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bc63e/6)